# When posting a link on Facebook, the title and thumbnail are missing

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url, post, linker

When I try to post a link from my blog on Facebook, either directly by copy/pasting the url or using a Wordpress plugin, Facebook "refuses" to pick up the title and the thumbnail picture of the post.

I've had this problem from time to time for a couple of months, but for the past 3 days I haven't been able to post a single post from my blog to Facebook and I can't see what would be the problem.

This is how it should work:

[image: This is how it should work.]

This is what actually happens when I post a link from my blog:

[image: This is what actually happens when I post a link from my blog.]

Has anyone experienced something like this or has any idea of why this isn't working for me? I can post other links on Facebook, it's just my blog that's screwing with me :o

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug within Facebook's code:

http://www.addthis.com/blog/2011/03/09/problem-with-sharing-to-facebook/

Looks like its being fixed/is fixed?

Also, make sure these tags are outputted:

```
<meta name="title" content="Title NOT Case Sensitive" />
<meta name="description" content="Description HERE" />
<link rel="image_src" href="Full URL to Image (include domain)" />
```

Comment: Even if they have "fixed" it, I still have a problem and can't share anything from my blog, even when I'm not using the "Share" button. Doesn't make any change with the meta tags either... Argh, this is so annoying. But thanks for the help :)

Comment: +1 for `image_src`,, @Sara i think FB caches the previews, you might try after a few hours or a day..?